# Re-Order a ListView in Xamarin Forms by Drag and Drop functionality

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, drag-and-drop

Need to Re-Order a ListView in Xamarin Forms by Drag and Drop functionality.
Any sample would be of help.

No 3rd party can be used.

Unable to write the renderers for Xamarin Forms -iOS

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: I am new to Xamarin Forms... need to re-order the Listview using ListView Renderer... and not UITableView @MihailDuchev

Answer (score 0):

From a quick google search I found following.
I did not look quite deep but a good example to start with.
Should be the example you're looking for. Only for iOS so need to adapt it for Android.

https://canbilgin.wordpress.com/2018/03/04/re-order-listview-items-with-drag-drop-i/

Comment: I am new to Xamarin Forms... need to re-order the Listview using ListView Renderer... and not UITableView